# How to retrieve original TensorFlow frozen graph from .tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Basically I am trying to use google's pre trained [Speaker-id model](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/speech_speakerid_model_2017_11_14.tflite) for speaker detection. But this being a TensorFlow Lite model, I can't use it on my Linux pc. For that, I am trying to find a converter back to its frozen graph model. 
Any help on this converter or any direct way to use tensorflow Lite pretrained models on desktop itself, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the converter which generates tflite models to convert it back to a .pb file if that is what you're searching for.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md

Comment: where you found in the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/convert/cmdline_examples.md), converting .tflite to frozen model?

Comment: Looks like this was removed after r1.9, here's the [old version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md#to-graphdef).